# Matlab: "Error using randperm K must be less than or equal to N." even though K <= N?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random, computer-vision, siamese-network

```
dataFolderTrain = fullfile(PATH);

imdsTrain = imageDatastore(dataFolderTrain, ...
    'IncludeSubfolders',true, ...
    'LabelSource','foldernames');


idxs = randperm(numel(imdsTrain.Files),8);


batchSize = 10;
[pairImage1,pairImage2,pairLabel] = getSiameseBatch(imdsTrain,batchSize);
```

I am trying to implement my own Siamese Network. The full error is:

```
Error in SiameseTrainMine>getSimilarPair (line 357)
    pairIdxChoice = randperm(numel(idxs),2);

Error in SiameseTrainMine>getSiameseBatch (line 334)
            [pairIdx1,pairIdx2,pairLabels(i)] = getSimilarPair(imds.Labels);

Error in SiameseTrainMine (line 22)
[pairImage1,pairImage2,pairLabel] = getSiameseBatch(imdsTrain,batchSize);
```

However if I type `"randperm(numel(idxs),2)"` into the console it works fine and `"numel(idxs)"` returns 8

Comment: The "idxs" variable inside a call of external functions is not the same as the one visible  in base workspace. You'll have to dig inside the function call to see what's happening there.

Comment: The error doesn’t match the code. This means we cannot help. Also, you don’t have a [mre], which again means we cannot help. All we can do here is guess. My guess is you misunderstand the value of your variables. Use the debugger!